# Can't inject HTTP service using Angular2 with karma/jasmine: Uncaught ReferenceError: Zone is not defined

Tags: angular, ionic2, karma-jasmine

During the build, karma is reporting

```
Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught ReferenceError: Zone is not defined
```

The issue traces back to the "node_modules\@angular\core\testing\fake_async.js" file. I'm using Angular 2.2.1 and its an Ionic2-RC4 project.

I'm trying to test an HTTP service.  The following is the contents of the spec file:

```
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BaseRequestOptions, HttpModule, Http, Response, ResponseOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { TestService } from './test-service';

describe('Bible Service', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpModule],
            providers: [
                TestService,
                {
                    provide: Http,
                    useFactory: (mockBackend, options) => {
                        return new Http(mockBackend, options);
                    },
                    deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
                },
                MockBackend,
                BaseRequestOptions
            ]
        });
    });

    it('should get a verse', () => {
        inject([TestService, MockBackend], (service, mockBackend) => {
            expect(service.getTest()).toBe("yes");
        });
    });
});
```

karma correctly runs the file if I don't include the beforeEach, so the problem has something to do with the injection code.  any help would be appreciated.

here is the test-service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class TestService
{
    constructor(private http: Http)
    {
    }
    getTest()
    {
        return "yes";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what the issue here is exactly, but I solved it by patterning my testing solution off of the project here: https://github.com/lathonez/clicker.  I suspect its a versioning issue and has something to do with the specific requirements of angular2.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is the way you are using `inject`. It should not be _inside_ the test case, but instead _wrap_ the test case: `it('...', inject([], () => {}))`

Comment: thanks peeskillet, i get the error even if the inject function is removed and I use a simple "expect(1).toBe(1);" statement.  But its good to know that could be an issue